# Identify and match duplicate columns

Tags: r

I've got a dataset with columns of values, and need to find if any columns are matching in every row. I've been able to find which columns have a duplicate using:

```
S1 <- c(80,80,0,0,100)
S2 <- c(90,90,0,0,100)
S3 <- c(80,80,0,0,100)
eg <- data.frame(S1,S2,S3)
duplicated(t(eg))
```

where S1 and S3 are identical. This returns:

```
S1 = FALSE
S2 = FALSE
S3 = TRUE
```

So I know S3 is a duplicate of either S1 or S2, but I'm unsure which. Is there any terms I can add to help me determine which columns are identical to one another? Something like this:

```
S1 = S3
S2 = Unique
S3 = S1
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have added in a (hopefully) useful sample.

Comment: What outcome do you want if there is more than one duplicate? For example, if an S4 was also a duplicate of an S1. Or do you only have the three columns?

Comment: I have many columns, and I would need to know which three (or four...) are identical as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function returns a list of duplicate column groups:

```
get_identical_columns <- function(df) {
  cols_with_duplicates <- names(which(duplicated(t(df))))
  duplicate_column_groups <- lapply(cols_with_duplicates, function(column) {
                               names(which(apply(df, 2, identical, df[, column])))
                             })
  unique(duplicate_column_groups)
}
```

Say you have the following data in a data frame called `df`:

```
  a b c d e
  1 1 1 1 1
  2 2 2 2 2
  3 3 4 4 4
  4 4 5 5 5
  5 5 7 7 7
```

Columns `a` and `b` are identical to each other, as are columns `c`, `d`, and `e`. Running the above function will give you a list of the groups of column names that are identical to each other:

```
get_identical_columns(df)

# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b"

# [[2]]
# [1] "c" "d" "e"
```

The function first finds the `names` of `which` columns have duplicates, identified using your `duplicated(t(df))` method. We then use `lapply` so that for each one of those column names, we find all columns identical to it (including itself). The call to `unique` is to remove repeated results in the situation when there are 3 or more duplicate columns.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! (FYI, in case anyone else is trying it, the bottom bit of code should read 'get_identical_columns' instead of 'get_duplicate_columns'.

Comment: @kaigg I'm glad that helped, and thanks for pointing out the typo - fixed it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `duplicated` on the transpose

```
duplicated(t(eg))
#   S1    S2    S3 
#FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

If we need the column names of `duplicated` columns

```
eg1 <- t(eg)
i1 <- duplicated(eg1)|duplicated(eg1, fromLast = TRUE)
names(i1)[i1]
```

Or use `split`

```
split(names(i1), i1)
#$`FALSE`
#[1] "S2"

#$`TRUE`
#[1] "S1" "S3"
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating a dummy dataset, one can cross the columns to compare and check to see if all the rows are the same through a `purrr` loop. These can then be extracted from the dataset to have a version with only the duplicate columns.

```r
# Load library
library(tidyverse)

# Create data that has one column with all the same rows
test_data <- tibble(col1 = rnorm(100), col2 = runif(1), col3 = runif(1))
test_data <- test_data %>% mutate(col4 = col2)

# Create combinations of rows to compare
combination1 <- combn(names(test_data), 2, simplify = T)[1,]
combination2 <- combn(names(test_data), 2, simplify = T)[2,]

# Input of combinations for loop
input <- list(combination1, combination2)

# Index list where combinations identical
index <- pmap(input, ~identical(test_data[[..1]], test_data[[..2]]))

# Pull data that are identical, with their specific names
identical <- tibble(!!sym(combination1[index==T]) := test_data[[combination1[index==T]]],
                    !!sym(combination2[index==T]) := test_data[[combination2[index==T]]])

identical
```

This will return a dataset with the duplicated columns. Although there could be more efficient/simpler ways to do this, I believe this example can likely be expanded to your specific use case.

```r
# A tibble: 100 x 2
    col2  col4
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.901 0.901
 2 0.901 0.901
 3 0.901 0.901
 4 0.901 0.901
 5 0.901 0.901
 6 0.901 0.901
 7 0.901 0.901
 8 0.901 0.901
 9 0.901 0.901
10 0.901 0.901
# ... with 90 more rows
```